# How to return end reading from socket on end of HTTP request?

Tags: c, sockets, http

I need to write a simple HTTP web server in C using Sockets. So far I have established socket connection and can receive the input (using `fdopen` to attach sockets to `FILE *` and `fgets` afterwards), however I don't know how to stop reading when I get `\r\n\r\n`. So far I have tried with matching the position with `strstr`, but it doesn't seem to work. What is a proper way of terminating read when double newline is met?

This is part of my code at the moment:

```
char buf[BUFSIZE];
int read_fd = client_fd; //client_fd is the connecting client socket
int write_fd = dup2(client_fd,1); // duplicate the file descriptor

// Wrap the socket file descriptor using FILE* file handles,
// for both reading and writing.
FILE *read_fh = fdopen(read_fd, "r");
FILE *write_fh = fdopen(write_fd, "w");

int done = 0;

int result = 1;
while (!done) {
    // Read one line from the client
    if (!fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, read_fh)) {
        break; // connection was interrupted?
    }

    char *cr = strstr(buf, "\r\n\r\n");
    if (cr) {
        fprintf(write_fh, "%s", buf);
        done=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do that fdopen stuff. Just use read() to read characters off the socket, and stop reading when \r\n\r\n is received. You probably want non-blocking IO, BTW.

Comment: So basically I read byte by byte and check if I have the `\r\n\r\n` sequence and then terminate? Also isn't non-blocking IO one where the function returns immediately - so this is connected when using `read()`, so that each byte is immediately processed?

Comment: You don't want to terminate reading at the double newline. That delimits the headers. You then want to read the body, if any. Unclear what, you're asking. NB don't bother with non-blocking I/O for a simple server: this is is a red herring.

Comment: @SantaClaus , nope , read() can read a buffered size data(means you can read chunk of data u just need to know the expected type) https://linux.die.net/man/3/read also if you're using winsoc just check it's api it has a recv() method it also exist on linux https://linux.die.net/man/2/recv

Comment: Okay, so when actually should I detect that the client request has been terminated and start parsing it to get the HTTP response? I thought that double newline is the flag that indicated that the request is over.

Comment: @EJP Why is non-blocking IO a "red herring"?

Comment: do you combine the chunks you receive from the socket and then use `strstr` or do you use `strstr` on each chunk separately ?

Comment: @BjornA. I think it's a bit of an overkill to write asynchronous IO for someone who is just learning. he should save it for some time later

Comment: @DavidHaim non-blocking != asynchronous ;)

If he doesn't use non-blocking reads, his next question will probably be "how do I stop read() from blocking". YMMV.

Comment: @BjornA. non blocking IO == asynchronous IO.

Comment: @DavidHaim : man 7 aio . That's async IO. I have no idea what you're talking about...

Comment: I have updated my original post with the code that I am using. My BUFSIZE is 2000. I use `strstr` on the buffer that is read, so I think it should read the message until the BUFSIZE is full.

Comment: the tricky thing is to detect `\r\n\r\n` WITHOUT reading 1 byte at a time

Comment: `fgets` won't ever return \r\n\r\n because that's two lines and it reads one line at a time.

Comment: I guess this is my problem then...I guess I have to use `read()` to read the request...is there a way to do it using `fgets`?

Comment: You need to read the HTTP headers line-by-line until `\r\n\r\n` is encountered, then you need to parse the headers to determine 1) if a response body is present, 2) what format the response body is being sent as so you can know how to read it correctly, and 3) how to detect when the response body ends. See [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) for details. `fgets()` is not a good choice to use, since you don't know how long the header lines will be.  HTTP does not have a line length limitation.